# checking for existing user in mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying this for several days now and am having problems with the code. I am trying tp learn php and mysql/MariaDB and am working on a multi user login system that allows for administrators and users.

So far I have the following working:

- users can register
- users can log-in and log-out if already registered (are directed to an index page based on user level
- administrator is directed to "admin" home page based on admin level
- administrators can create a new user from admin area (no access for user level)
- only difference between registration page and the admin create user page is that the admin create user page allows the assigning the role of either user or admin (no option for this on registration page)

My problem that I am running into is that I want to add a check to prevent the duplication of user names (newly registering users or admin created users can't create a new user if name already taken). I have tried inserting a check to see but it still adds the user even if that username already exists.

I was wondering if someone could look at the code I have and see where I am going wrong.

Here is my administrator create user code:

```
<?php include('../functions.php') ?>

if (!isAdmin()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../login.php');
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL - Create user</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
    <style>
        .header {
            background: #003366;
        }
        button[name=register_btn] {
            background: #003366;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Admin - create user</h2>
    </div>
    
    <form method="post" action="create_user.php">

        <?php echo display_error(); ?>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>User type</label>
            <select name="user_type" id="user_type" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="user">User</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_1">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_2">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="register_btn"> + Create user</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    **Here is Register page:**
    <?php include('functions.php') ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Register</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="register.php">
        <?php echo display_error(); ?>
        <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">User Name*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email*</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_1" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_2" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="register_btn">Register</button>
        </div>
        <p>
            Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
        </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here are all my functions:

```
    <?php 
session_start();

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('removed variables to connect to database this works');

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors   = array(); 

// call the register() function if register_btn is clicked
if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    register();
}

function register(){
    // call these variables with the global keyword to make them available in function
    global $db, $errors, $username, $email;

    // receive all input values from the form. Call the e() function
    // defined below to escape form values
    $username    =  e($_POST['username']);
    $email       =  e($_POST['email']);
    $password_1  =  e($_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2  =  e($_POST['password_2']);
    
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

$result=mysqli_query($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)
       {
        echo"name already exists";
}

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Username is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($email)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($password_1)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
    }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = hash('sha256', $password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        // excecute insert query 

        if (isset($_POST['user_type'])) {
            $user_type = e($_POST['user_type']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$email', '$user_type', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['success']  = "New user successfully created!!";
            header('location: home.php');
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$email', 'user', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

            // get id of the created user
            $logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

            $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_id); // put logged in user in session
            $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');              
        }
    }

}
            // ge

// return user array from their id
function getUserById($id){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $user;
}

// escape string
function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
}

function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="error">';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'<br>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// log user out if logout button clicked
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    header("location: login.php");
}

// call the login() function if register_btn is clicked
if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    login();
}

// LOGIN USER
function login(){
    global $db, $username, $errors;

    // grap form values
    $username = e($_POST['username']);
    $password = e($_POST['password']);

    // make sure form is filled properly
    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    // attempt login if no errors on form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = hash(sha256, $password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
            // check if user is admin or user
            $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                header('location: admin/home.php');       
            }else{
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}

function isAdmin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function I have been adding the code to is the register function As you can see, I selected all from my users table and assigned it to a variable (the username variable was assigned just above it from the Post Action. I then did a mysqli query on that variable and assigned this to another variable. Then I tried to say if the number of rows did not equal zero, then the username existed.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If any can provide some insight, please let me know. I know this code is probably not the best. I am trying this out in my local environment to learn. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably best to have this enforced in the database honestly - `ALTER TABLE users 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX unq_username(username);`

Comment: Before you take another step, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Hi Dave and Strawberry. Never thought of enforcing in the database. Can you still put out error messages on webpage if database uses unique key? Any good forums that you have come across?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: hey everyone, thanks for the advice. I know I am making a lot of security mistakes right now. I am in the process of learning and would like to learn the right way now. I have briefly looked into sql injections and using PDO. could you use password hash and verify using salts? I just used hash256 in my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The propblem is in the `mysqli_query` function, this function needs at least 2 parameters, the first one is the link to your database, so your code should be something like:

```php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db_name");

/* your code */

$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: Thanks Sami. I will try your suggestion in the morning. I know my database connection works as I am able to add users and values (I just took the values out for the purpose of posting on here). Nice to have an extra pair of eyes and someone with more knowledge. Will update tomorrow

Comment: Hi Sami, thanks for everything; I got it to work. It was a mistake that I just couldn't see. One of those "Dohhh" moments.